# Using multiple ">" CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

Given this html :

```
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
       I want to apply my style to this
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            But not to this
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to apply style to the cells that are first level children of the table.

I thought I could use this :

```
#my-table > tr > td {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

... But it doesn't work. Is it because you can't use multiple `>` selectors ? How can I do it ?

Comment: nested tables? is this a layout, if so, then not using tables will help - also, just using classes on the elements you want to target is much easier than trying to copy HTML structure in css selectors

Comment: @ToniLeigh the inner table is not mine (it's a third party date picker)

Comment: I'd probably try a class on the lowest level thing you control then (a `<td>` by looks of it)

Comment: Yes that's what I'll do (sigh)

Comment: classes are better anyway, re-usable, not tied to HTML structure or a particular element (when you use a date picker somewhere else you won't have to make sure it's parent is a TD) - 3rd party stuff is awkward though, you might even have to use `!important`

Comment: @yannick1976 *sigh*? That's how you're [supposed to do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS#Avoid_the_descendant_selector.21); matching hierarchical selectors is way more expensive than a class. Besides, having a descriptive classes is much more useful in the long run (e.g. when making modifications). Use it whenever you can.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two aspects to what's going on:

1. The browser will insert a `tbody` element if you don't include one (or at least, most do, most of the time; I always use an explicit one, so I don't know the edge cases), and so even if you don't have it in your HTML, you need it in your selector if you're using `>` (the child combinator). That would change your selector to `#my-table > tbody > tr > td`. (I advocate always including `tbody` explicitly in the HTML, just to avoid confusion and edge cases.)
2. The table inside the `td` *inherits* its color from the `td` it's inside. So although your selector targets the correct elements, their *descendant* elements inherit the color.

You can work around that by giving an explicit color to `#my-table td` elements, and then the special color only to `#my-table > tbody > tr > td` elements.

Example (note the `tbody` in the HTML and also in the selector):

```css
#my-table td {
  color: black;
}
#my-table > tbody > tr > td {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        I want to apply my style to this
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              But not to this
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In a comment you've said you don't control the inner table. If you control the *outer* table, you can solve this by just putting a class on the cells you want to apply the rule to, and then have the rule only apply to `td`s with that class:

Example (note the `tbody` in the HTML and also in the selector):

```css
#my-table > tbody > tr > td.first {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">
        I want to apply my style to this
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              But not to this
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Alas, I can't do it though because the inner table is not mine (it's a third party date picker), and I don't want to duplicate the properties. But it looks like it's as good as it gets...

Comment: @yannick1976: Sounds like fun. :-) But the good news is that if you control the outer table but not the inner, there is another approach: Use a class on your first `td`. I've added an example of that.

Comment: I couldn't find a reference to it on MDN so maybe you can't but is it possible to use the value `initial` on color?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Not [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-color), no. I don't even see anything like that in the latest [snapshot](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#foreground).

Comment: Why not just use `.first` as selector in the second example?

Comment: @transistor09 `.first` is a class selector. If you meant `:nth-child(1)` or `:first-child` or jQuery's `:first`, that would fail to apply to other cells, and I understood from the question (and the OP [later confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521614/using-multiple-css-selectors/33521751?noredirect=1#comment54825726_33522209)) they want this for **all** first-level `td`s, not just the first one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well then A: yannick1976 has to edit his question B: he's fighting inheritance, in which case he needs to reset the style for inner table

Answer (score 2):

Hi now you can try to this way

```css
#my-table > tbody> tr > td {
    color: #ff0000;
}
#my-table td{color:#000;}
```

```html
<table id="my-table"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
       I want to apply my style to this
    </td>
    <td>
      <table><tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            But not to this
          </td>
        </tr></tbody>
      </table>  
    </td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

> > The  tag is used to group the body content in an HTML table.
>
> The  element is used in conjunction with the  and
>    elements to specify each part of a table (body, header,
>   footer).
>
> Browsers can use these elements to enable scrolling of the table body
>   independently of the header and footer. Also, when printing a large
>   table that spans multiple pages, these elements can enable the table
>   header and footer to be printed at the top and bottom of each page.
>
> The  tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a
>    element, after any , , and 
>   elements.

**[more about tbody](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/tbody)**

Comment: This still highlights `but not to this`

Comment: Moreover, code/markup without explanation is usually *not useful*.

Comment: There is no `tbody` in your HTML but on your CSS… Thats weird.

Comment: And that quote (if it's a quote) about `tbody` is Just Plain Wrong when it says *"for example, you may choose to set the height of the tbody area to a fixed amount, and let the content in that area scroll, so that the table’s header and footer sections remain visible on screen"* If only that were ***remotely*** true, cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see it you need the :first-child as well, otherwise you are stil hitting the last TD, if you want a border on it:

```css
 #my-table > tbody > tr > td:first-child  {
   color: #ff0000;
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      I want to apply my style to this
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            But not to this
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `:first-child` targets the first child by order, not by nesting level. If I have another first-level `td`, the style is not applied to it.

Comment: True if you add another first-level td, then this dosnt work, i only looked at your example :)

Answer (score 2):

`color` has the property that it's being applied to all of it's childs. Therefor you will need to limit it. You can do this with `>` and `:nth-child(n)`

```
#my-table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Your HTML should have a `tbody` but it might not be necessary, browsers will create them for you, but it's advised to use `tbody` yourself.

You can modify this if your tables are getting larger.. for example with using formulas like `3n+1`, `odd/even` etc.. also you can use multiple spaces or `>` and element tags to specify all your needs. Depending on what you want.

[More info about nth-child() here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)